# How to pass parameters from a button in REACTJS?

Tags: reactjs

I want to show only the paragraphs related to the selected chapter. To do this I did STATE with the selected Chapter number (the chapters are in numbers)
When I view the paragraphs in the page load it works fine.

I also want to make a list of buttons that move to the other chapters. The problem is that when I press the above buttons it does not change the STATE and I did console.log and really saw that the parameter I pass is incorrect. Where am I wrong in the code?

```
 {allChapters.map(allChapter =>
     <button key={allChapter} onClick={(allChapter) => this.handleChange(allChapter)}>
         {allChapter}
     </button>
 )}

 handleChange = (chapNum) => {
     this.setState(({ currentChapter }) => ({ currentChapter: chapNum }))
     console.log('chapNum', chapNum);
 };
```

[console.log()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1My4.jpg)

It is important to note: `{allChapter}` is mirror number (1,2,3, ...) and the problem is not in it.

Comment: Can you also post an example of the 'allChapters' array here?

Comment: Tough not the problem here, but why `this.setState(({ currentChapter }) => ({ currentChapter: chapNum }))`? For your case: `this.setState({ currentChapter: chapNum })` would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code, the only thing you do is to rename the default onClick event parameter to `allChapter`. Just do this instead:

```
{allChapters.map(allChapter =>
    <button key={allChapter} onClick={() => this.handleChange(allChapter)}>
       {allChapter}
    </button>
)}
```

Btw, you should change the variable name `allChapter` to `chapter` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<button key={allChapter} onClick={(allChapter) => this.handleChange(allChapter)}>
  {allChapter}
</button>
```

By doing this, you rename the default onClick event parameter with

> allChapter

Then you pass this renamed event to the handleChange. It's why, your console.log shows an event.

The correct way to pass your parameter is :

```
<button key={allChapter} onClick={() => this.handleChange(allChapter)}>
  {allChapter}
</button>
```